# NHibernate one-to-many removing related records

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have three tables with the following structure:

```
Todo
    Id
    Name

User
    Id
    Name

TodoUser
    Id
    TodoId
    UserId
    Status
```

For `Todo.ResponsibleUsers` I have created the following mapping:

```
private IList<TodoUser> responsibleUsers = new List<TodoUser>();
[Bag(0, Name = "ResponsibleUsers", Cascade = CascadeStyle.AllDeleteOrphan, Table = "TodoUser", Inverse = true)]
[Key(1, Column = "TodoId")]
[OntToMany(2, ClassType = typeof(TodoUser))]
public virtual IList<TodoUser> ResponsibleUsers {
    get { return responsibleUser; }
    set { responsibleUsers = (IList<TodoUser>)value; }
}
```

Does the property `ResponsibleUsers` have to be of type `IList<TodoUser>` or can it also be of type `List<TodoUser>`?
I would like to do something like `todo.ResponsibleUsers.RemoveAll(itemsToRemove);` which is not possible on an `IList<TodoUser>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question:

> Does the property ResponsibleUsers have to be of type `IList<TodoUser>` or can it also be of type `List<TodoUser>`?

Check the doc:

> ## [Chapter 6. Collection Mapping](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections)
>
> ## 6.1. Persistent Collections
>
> **NHibernate requires that persistent collection-valued fields be
>   declared as a generic interface type**, for example:
>
> ```
> public class Product
> {
>     private string serialNumber;
>     private ISet<Part> parts = new HashSet<Part>();
>
>     public ISet<Part> Parts
>     {
>         get { return parts; }
>         set { parts = value; }
>     }
>
>     public string SerialNumber
>     {
>         get { return serialNumber; }
>         set { serialNumber = value; }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> The actual interface might be
>   `System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<T>`,
>   `System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>`,
>   `System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<K, V>`,
>   `System.Collections.Generic.ISet<T>`

So, yes, we must use interface.

To solve the issue with

> I would like to do something like `todo.ResponsibleUsers.RemoveAll(itemsToRemove)`;

We can implement some custom extension method as

```
public static class Ext
{
    public static void RemoveAll(this IList<T> list, IEnumerable<T> toRemove)
    {
        ... // remove items matching toRemove from the list
    }
```